# Laravel (and generic) framework setting for "Public" folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

I tried to make [Laravel](http://www.laravel.com/) works on my environment (MAMP) but i'm stuck in this situation.

The `index.php` file of Laravel is into a subfolder called "public", so if I want to test my application I need to access it with this url `http://localhost/laravel/public/` 
but I want access with `http://localhost/laravel`

I tried to set an htaccess with this rows but it doesn't work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
</IfModule>
```

I'm not sure that this htaccess can resolves this situation, I get a 404 generated by Lavarel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a virtualhost. Dayle Ress covers this in the first chapter in his Laravel book: https://web.archive.org/web/20121013083457/http://daylerees.com/2012/03/25/laravel-getting-started/

Answer (score 4):

Put .htacess file in root with code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

public is actually the part that should be your document root.

Comment: In my testing environment I have every sites in locahost/ folder