# How to run laravel in root directory without the public folder?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, debian

I am running the latest version of **laravel** on my own server running **Debian** and **Apache2**.

The contents of **laravel** are located in **`/var/www`** which is what my domain name is pointed to however all of the functionality happens through the **`public`** directory so I would have to go to *http://mydomain.com/public* to access anything.

I would like to change it so that I only have to access *http://mydomain.com*. Is this possible?

How can I change this? Would I have to move everything up another level to the parent at **`/var`**?

I haven't found anything online so far that says that it is possible, or that it is a good idea.

Comment: Check this... http://stackoverflow.com/a/12827445/388382

Comment: Yep, the link kanenas.net posted has the two answers: 1) Re-direct your virtual host, and 2) if you absolutely can't, there's an .htaccess you can place in your root folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not your problem, you need to point the virtual host to the public folder.

Comment: I am using other subdirectories on the domain too... Or, is that possible through larval? Or... Am I going about it the wrong way?

Comment: You should really modify your server setup instead of the code base. Add those subdirectories to the public folder and point the vhost to /var/www/public

Comment: Thank you. I have done that and it works. Is there no harm in putting extra directories within the larval public directory then?

Comment: Not as long as you want to those files to be publicly accessible.

Comment: Virtual host is a good solution but virtual host is not always available in a shared hosting server even though the questioner did not mention about that.

Comment: Try **My Solution** It will work **everywhere**.  check Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222509/laravel-not-detecting-files-from-public-folder/69517681#69517681

Answer (score 2):

Add a file in laravel root directory, name it as .htaccess and put this inside,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
```

It will be fixed surely.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me, as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16569078/3091980

Move all contents of the /public folder down a level. Then update the include lines in index.php to point to the correct location - if it's down a level, remove the "../".

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I deleted  my old answer .. that was if u rename server.php to index then it will work but of course not because laarvel not load all service. so you have to paste into root all public folder file. and remove "../" from everywhere in index.php

Answer (score 0):

Locate your `httpd.conf` and change the part that DocumentRoot `"/var/www"` to `"/var/www/public"` and override directory to allow `.htaccess` file of laravel

```
...
DocumentRoot "/var/www/public"
...
<Directory "/var/www/public">
   AllowOverride None
   Options None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

...