# How to run Laravel from root directory, not from public?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

By default, Laravel project is run from the *public* directory. For this, I must enter http://localhost/public/.

How do I configure Laravel so that the website will appear to be from http://localhost/?

Comment: you can configure it with your web server. are you using nginx? For every domain, you also setup a root directory, which should be /dir/to/laravel/public instead of /dir/to/laravel

Comment: If you're not using a web server you can also use `php -S localhost:80 -t public` from the root directory

Comment: I dont have access to command line also to nginx, it is simple hosting

Comment: You can rename file that will be find in root folder name with **server.php** . just rename in **index.php**.

Comment: use this link for better understand. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547891/how-to-run-laravel-in-root-directory-without-the-public-folder/65716511#65716511

Answer (score 15, accepted):

•Go to mainproject/public>>

```
a.  .htacess
b.  favicon.ico
c.  index.php
d.  robots.txt
e.  web.config
```

1.cut these 5 files from the public folder, and then paste on the main project folder that’s means out side of public folder… mainproject/files

2.Next after paste ,open index.php ,modify

```
•require __DIR__.'/…/bootstrap/autoload.php';  to
•require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

3. modify

   $app = require_once **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/app.php';  to

   $app = require_once **DIR**.'/bootstrap/app.php';

**you can also watch this video for better understanding**----------------

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GboCYqEbKN0

Comment: bro i have it's better answer check my

Answer (score 3):

Setup your webserver (probably Apache or NginX) to use the public folder of your laravel app as root directory. Or use a `public_html` folder and symlink it to your public folder, which basically does the same.

Comment: For it to work well, you have to modify 3 lines in your index file in the root directory as for Laravel 8.6.x
`#1 if (file_exists($maintenance = __DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php')) { to if (file_exists($maintenance = __DIR__.'/storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {`

`#2  require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
 to require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';`

`#3 $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
 to $app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
`

Answer (score 0):

open your project in visual studio code

in new terminal type

```
php artisan serve
```

and goto
http://127.0.0.1:8000